# Loading image dataset in numpy arrays in python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

I have 6 different images. I want to store them together in a single numpy array. Is that possible? If yes, how can I do that?

```py
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import listdir
from numpy import asarray
import numpy as np

for i in range(1,6):
    image=Image.open(str(i)+'.jpg')
    image=image.resize((100,100))
    temp=asarray(image)
    print(np.append(X_train,temp,axis=0))
```

This raises the following Exception:

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Answer (score 2):

you can create a list of arrays and the convert back to numpy array

```
list_of_pics = list()
for i in range(1,6):
    image=Image.open(str(i)+'.jpg')
    image=image.resize((100,100))
    list_of_pics.append(np.asarray(image))
new_array = np.array(list_of_pics)
```

the final dimentions of new_array should be (6,100,100)

Comment: I am getting shape as (6,100,100,3) but I want shape (6,100,100)

Comment: I think you're getting exactly what you want, because the 3 last dimensions are the RGB values that define the color value. If you're not interested in the color you can use the mean value for the brigthness, in this way you can convert the image in black and white.
Check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brightness